# converted my flutter into apk file and it wont work

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, apk

i have a flutter app that has firebase and firestore as backend,
it works fine on the emulator when i changed it into apk, but on the real device on the log in page the loading circle get stuck and the app wont proceed the log in procedure.

i don't why does this happen? it works fine as normal flutter on the device but when its apk it only works on emulator.
here is the pic of the laading being stuck

[the pic of the mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAL5z.jpg)

Comment: Impossible to know based on this little information. I suggest that you hook up your device to your computer and debug as if it was the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the internet permission in your androidManifest.xml?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

The permission is on by default in a debug build, but not in a release build

Answer (score 0):

go to your flutter project and go /android/app/src/main and open AndroidManifest.xml and add this line under the package tag

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```